# What is extern?

Tags: objective-c

I know that 'extern' means that it's declaration and definition are not available in the same source files. However i don't see any significant use of it.

Lets assume i have three classes Employee, Department and Library.

lets say we have something like this in Library class

```
extern NSString *abc;
```

we use it something like this in Department class.

Department.h

```
NSString *abc;
```

Department.m

```
abc = @"abcdefg";
```

and something like this is Employee class.

Employee.m

```
NSString *abc = @"xyz";
```

When we look at classes Employee and Department they look just like normal variable declarations and definitions.

So, My question is what is it's special power?

Comment: http://nshipster.com/c-storage-classes/

Comment: extern is a C feature. Objective-C have it only because ObjC is trying to be C-compatible. So yes, in purely object-oriented ObjC code you will not need it.

Comment: @Will More correctly, Objective-C is a full superset of C. It's not trying to be C-compatible, it *is* C, plus a lot more. But you are right, a properly designed, truly OO Objective-C code base isn't going to use some of the C concepts like `extern` global variables.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, `extern` tells the compiler not to complain that there's a declaration of the variable without a definition of it. Though, Xcode doesn't complain about this anyway because all Objective-C global variables are secretly declared `extern`.

You could technically leave the `extern` directive off, but you might as well be explicit. It still means something to the programmer who sees it.